# System Requirements For Angular Library

Tags: angular-library, system-requirements

I am developing a Angular application and doing documentation for the same.

I am aware of minimum system requirements to be specified for third party software used for developing my application like required processor speed, os, RAM needed etc.

Is there anything applicable like Hardware/Software specification to be provided for the Libraries used in my Angular Application other than browser support ?

Answer (score 1):

Each version of Angular has list of supported browsers.

https://angular.io/guide/browser-support

Answer (score 0):

You can check this site that outlines the minimum system requirements

https://help.boldreports.com/report-viewer-sdk/angular-reporting/system-requirements/

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).